# Close the pop-up menu when user reach the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, menu

I have a simple menu that is opening on click.

What I would need is to:

1. open menu/hamburger on click top left
2. user read all text and
   scrolling down
   3.3rd step - close/hide the pop up menu when user reach the end of the page

I kindly ask for a snippet of code to add at my js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle-nav").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".menu ul").toggleClass("active");
    });
    $(document).click(function(e){
      if(!e.target.closest("ul") && $(".menu a").hasClass("active")){
         $(".menu ul").toggleClass("active");
         $(".toggle-nav").toggleClass("active");
      }
    })
    
});
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/marledietrich/pen/qBNgEEg) is my codepen to test the function

great  solution?

p.s. obviously the action need to work every time the user toggle the hamburger button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your jQuery with this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".toggle-nav").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".menu ul").toggleClass("active");
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (!e.target.closest("ul") && $(".menu a").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".menu ul").toggleClass("active");
            $(".toggle-nav").toggleClass("active");
        }
    });


    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
        var hgt = $('.menu').height();
        var win = $(window).height();

        if (hgt - win === scrollPos) {
            $(".menu ul").toggleClass("active");
            $(".toggle-nav").toggleClass("active");
        }
    });

});
```

---

**Version 2:** With FadeOut

For this option to work you need to add `id="fadeout"` to the `ul` element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".toggle-nav").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".menu ul").toggleClass("active");
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (!e.target.closest("ul") && $(".menu a").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".menu ul").toggleClass("active");
            $(".toggle-nav").toggleClass("active");
        }
    });


    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
        var hgt = $('.menu').height();
        var win = $(window).height();

        if (hgt - win === scrollPos) {
            $('#fadeout').fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(".menu ul").toggleClass("active");
                $(".toggle-nav").toggleClass("active");
                $('#fadeout').removeAttr("style");
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Is there also a way to fade the menu when the menu get closed?

Comment: You can try "Version 2" with FadeOut

Comment: How to also fade in when open @ 54ka ? sorry to bother your skills ;)

Comment: I tried but to do this you will have to change too many things in your code. Better not to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this code that may help you (it works almost for all the browsers),
It left just the code to close the popup

**Update** 
(the URL in the comment I couldn't add it here).

Comment: hehe this is my codepen already!  the link you send me is the same i posted

Comment: check this one  https://codepen.io/youba/pen/ZEOwYyR ( I couldn't add the URL)

Comment: Thanks Youba but does not close or alert anything when i reach the bottom of the page

Comment: it does work for me!! check if you are in the right URL not the old one

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var menu = document.getElementById("Menu");
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= menu.offsetHeight) {
      if($(".menu a").hasClass("active")){
         $(".menu ul").toggleClass("active");
         $(".toggle-nav").toggleClass("active");
      }
    }
};
```

Then on your `<ul>` tag, give it the id Menu

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the jQuery `scroll` to detect if the scroll reach the bottom and add the toggle when true like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    if ($(".menu a").hasClass("active")) {
      $(".menu ul").toggleClass("active");
      $(".toggle-nav").toggleClass("active");
    }
  }
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/GaabrieeLp/pen/rNLPapQ)